# Etsy RestSharp OAuth - signature_invalid

Tags: c#, oauth, restsharp, etsy

Hello i have a problem with umlauts (ä,ö,ü) while creating a new listing over the etsy api.
Without ä, ö or ü in my request the api works fine without any problems.

Here is my Code.

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var restClient = new RestClient("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2");
        restClient.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(etsyCredentials.ConsumerKey, etsyCredentials.ConsumerSecret, etsyCredentials.OAuth_Token, etsyCredentials.OAuth_Token_Secret, RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1);


        string requestParameters = "/listings?quantity=1&title=testartikel mit Ä&description=Testartikel, Bitte nicht kaufen.&price=0.99&taxonomy_id=6451&who_made=i_did&when_made=2010_2019&is_supply=false&shipping_template_id=60205488400&renew=True&state=draft&language=de";
        var request = new RestRequest(requestParameters);
        request.Method = Method.POST;

        IRestResponse irestResponse = restClient.Execute(request);
```

And here the Error:

> "oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=POST&https%3A%2F%2Fopenapi.etsy.com%2Fv2%2Flistings&description%3DTestartikel%252C%2520Bitte%2520nicht%2520kaufen.%26is_supply%3Dfalse%26language%3Dde%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dgn31uuabj1qv97zjqozgnsto%26oauth_nonce%3D02xdjk7bxv4id7mx%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1631170110%26oauth_token%3D8fc58d589855126dd880b3ac74eb1b%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26price%3D0.99%26quantity%3D1%26renew%3DTrue%26shipping_template_id%3D60205488400%26state%3Ddraft%26taxonomy_id%3D6451%26title%3Dtestartikel%2520mit%2520%25C3%2584%26when_made%3D2010_2019%26who_made%3Di_did"

could someone perhaps tell me what I have to do to successfully create requests with umlauts?

Comment: Hello Daniel, did you try to change the string value with an encoded one?
`string encodedRequestParameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(requestParameters, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);`
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QDpoVj

Comment: Hi Salih,
This generates a different error:
"The supplied uri doesn't map to a valid command"


When i ad the "/listings?" to the requeststring after encoding it throws the next different error:

"Using query parameters in the base URL is not supported for OAuth calls. Consider using AddDefaultQueryParameter instead"

Comment: Can you please create a new working dotnetfiddle as a copy of your code? Another option, you can try to contact the etsy platform about umlauts characters.

Comment: Hello Salih, thank you for your help. A fiddle won't help here without the API keys. The etsy support is unfortunately not helpful either, they do not respond to e-mails at all.

Comment: you can try to escape your request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=net-5.0